# Error in grouped_df_impl: cannot group column Category, of class 'list'

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to do some basic data manipulation. I'm starting with three lists:

```
CF.Item <- list("T1Rent", "T2Rent", "Sec.Deposit", "Landlord.Contrib", "Broker.Commission", "NNN", "OpEx", "RE.Tax")
Net.Present.Value <- list(T1Rent.npv, T2Rent.npv, Sec.Deposit.npv, Landlord.Contrib.npv, Broker.Commission.npv, NNN.npv, OpEx.npv, RE.Tax.npv)
Category <- list("Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash OUT", "Cash OUT", "Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash IN")
```

The variables xxxx.npv are all numeric. (They're calculated elsewhere in the code.)

Ultimately, I want to graph xxxx.npv by "Category".

I've tried several different ways of manipulating the lists into matrices, data frames, tibbles ... everything.

I've also tried these:

1: summarize

```
by_Cat <- cashcat %>% group_by(Category)
View(by_Cat)
```

2. ggplot

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_bar(data = list.npv,
                        aes(x = Category,
                            y = Net.Present.Value,
                            color = CF.Item),
                        stat = "identity")
p
```

But I always end up with errors about "Category".

Finally, I've searched the internet and S.O. for **hours**, and just can't figure it out.

What am I doing wrong / what is a good way to attack this?

Thanks.

Comment: Turn `category` into a vector

Comment: Try to `rbind` your lists. Look at `rbindlist` from `data.table` with the option `fill=TRUE`

Comment: i tried 'Category <- as.vector(list( ...' and 'Category <- as.vector( ... '. I still get the same error.

Comment: try `unlist(my_list)`

Comment: Also tried data.table::rbindlist. Tried both fill = TRUE and use.names = TRUE.

But still throwing errors - this time "Error in rbindlist: use.names=TRUE but no item of input list has any names."

Comment: @yeedle thanks, but not sure where to unlist(). should i start by not using a list in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are not really appropriate for this purpose. Vectors and dataframes, are much more useful for this. Take a look:

```r
library(tidyverse)
CF.Item <- list("T1Rent", "T2Rent", "Sec.Deposit", "Landlord.Contrib", "Broker.Commission", "NNN", "OpEx", "RE.Tax")
Net.Present.Value <- as.list(runif(8))
Category <- list("Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash OUT", "Cash OUT", "Cash IN", "Cash IN", "Cash IN")

df <- data_frame(
  Category = unlist(Category), 
  Net.Present.Value = unlist(Net.Present.Value), 
  CF.Item = unlist(CF.Item))
  ggplot(df, aes(x = Category,
           y = Net.Present.Value,
           color = CF.Item)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]